# How to add laravel query function lists in updateOrCreate eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to use updateOrCreate with multiple conditions and this condition can be applied occasionally if corresponding data are available. I am currently doing as first find the id if exists and if id exists update else create manually but now i want to use laravel given updateOrCreate function.

```
$existing = Student::where('name_last', $student['name_last'])
->where('name_first', $student['name_first'])
->where(function($query) use ($student) {
    if (array_key_exists('phone_preferred', $student) && !empty($student['phone_preferred'])) {
        $query->where('phone_preferred', $student['phone_preferred']);
    }

    if (array_key_exists('email_preferred', $student) && !empty($student['email_preferred'])) {
        $query->where('email_preferred', $student['email_preferred']);
    }

    if (array_key_exists('home_street_address_1', $student) && !empty($student['home_street_address_1'])) {
        $query->where('home_street_address_1', $student['home_street_address_1']);
    }

    if (array_key_exists('mailing_street_address_1', $student) && !empty($student['mailing_street_address_1'])) {
        $query->where('mailing_street_address_1', $student['mailing_street_address_1']);
    }

    if (array_key_exists('mailing_address_city', $student) && !empty($student['mailing_address_city'])) {
        $query->where('mailing_address_city', $student['mailing_address_city']);
    }

})->first();

 if($existing){
    try{
        Student::where('id', $existing->id)
        ->update($student);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
         $error_encountered = true;
         $error_arr[] = $e->getMessage();
         $error_row_numbers[] = $row_no; 
        }
}
```

I want to implement with something like:

```
try{
        Student::updateOrCreate(
                     ['name_first' => $student['name_first], 'name_last' => $student['name_last]], 
                    $student
           ); //I could not get how to implement other occasional where condition

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
         $error_encountered = true;
         $error_arr[] = $e->getMessage();
         $error_row_numbers[] = $row_no; 
        }
```

I want to include those occasional where function query to updateOrCreate method which is currently implementing in manual method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add all the attributes you want to check for in the array that you pass to `updateOrCreate`

```
// these are your required conditions
$conditions = [
    'name_first' => $student['name_first'],
    'name_last' => $student['name_last'],
];

// these are optional
$attributes = [
    'phone_preferred', 
    'email_preferred', 
    'home_street_address_1', 
    'mailing_street_address_1', 
    'mailing_address_city'
];

foreach($attributes as $attr){
    // check to see if the attribute exists on the student
    // and is not empty
    if(isset($student[$attr]) && !empty($student[$attr])){
        $conditions[$attr] = $student[$attr];
    }
}

Student::updateOrCreate($conditions);
```

Comment: Thank you. That is what I'm exactly looking.